# Is it possible to add some pattern to $Assumptions

Tags: assumptions

I apologize if it is a too elementary question but I could not find the appropriate documentation so far.

My goal is simple. I would like to add some assumptions that are defined in terms of patterns rather than symbols. 
For example, I would like to something like this

```
$Assumptions = { a[ ___ ] > 0 };
```

In my ideal world, this should set every expression with the `Head` `a` should be considered positive. Is it possible in Mathematica?

EDIT:
Thanks. Following the first comment and the first answer, I did the following experiment. I still got puzzled about the result. Maybe it is just because of the intricate interaction between `Integrate` and `$Assumptions`.

```
$Assumptions = {A[___] > 0, B > 0};

Integrate[ Exp[ - A[x] t] , {t, 0, \[Infinity]}]
Integrate[ Exp[ - B t] , {t, 0, \[Infinity]}]
(* output *)
ConditionalExpression[1/A[x], Re[A[x]] > 0]
1/B
```

In this example, `Integrate` does not make use of the fact `A[___]>0`.

Comment: It looks to me like it works. Starting from a fresh kernel, I executed `$Assumptions = {a[__] > 0};Refine[a[3] > 0]`, and the result was `True`. You should have just tried it! :) (As "simple" as this is, I never thought of it.)

Comment: @march Thanks. Indeed your example works. Can you comment on my experiment added now?

Comment: Well, `Integrate` assumes that its argument (and all variables) are all complex. It seems like `$Assumptions` is very conservative, in the sense that it will only apply the `A[___] >0` assumption if it knows it's real. if it knows `A[___]` is real. Add `Element[A[___], Reals]` to `$Assumptions`, and you don't get the conditional expression. I'm not sure about the differences between those two, though. That's interesting.

Comment: @march Your suggestion fixed the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Don't use uppercase initials on your symbols... that's just asking for trouble.

Comment: @ciao Thanks for you advice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is correct; you can also use the following forms, which are generally considered better suited to functional-programming style (in that you don't change the variables globally, just locally):

```
Block[
  {$Assumptions = (a[___] > 0)},
  code]
```

or, better yet,

```
Assuming[
  a[___] > 0,
  code]
```

**Edit**:

(In respond to the OP's code sample) I'm a bit surprised that the code treats A[x] and B differently, but the problem seems to come from an assumption that A[x] could be a complex number. This can be fixed with an additional assumption (also pointed out by march):

```
Assuming[
  {A[___] > 0, B > 0, A[___] \[Element] Reals},
  {Integrate[Exp[-A[x] t], {t, 0, \[Infinity]}],
   Integrate[Exp[-B t], {t, 0, \[Infinity]}]}]
```

> {1/A[x], 1/B}

I would be interested to hear if anyone else knows why A[x] and B are treated differently by the integration system. I initially thought it might be the assumption that x is a variable, but this example is slightly more illustrative:

```
Assuming[
  {c[___] > 0, c[x] > 0, f > 0},
  {Integrate[Exp[-c[1]*t], {t, 0, \[Infinity]}],
   Integrate[Exp[-c[x]*t], {t, 0, \[Infinity]}],
   Integrate[Exp[-f*t], {t, 0, \[Infinity]}]}]
```

> {ConditionalExpression[1/c[1], Re[c[1]] > 0], 1/c[x], 1/f}

It seems to me that assumptions containing patterns are treated differently than explicit assumptions, yet it is clear from my previous example (with `A[___] \[Element] Reals`) that assumptions with patterns are not just being ignored.

Comment: Thanks. Can you also comment on the added example?